# How to Secure specific Endpoint (in API Gateway ?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

In my AWS Cloud environment, I have an API Gateway that invokes a Lambda function from a specific route.
I would like to add an additional authorization mechanism but I am not sure in which level (API Gateway level ?) in the form of a Lambda function.
Basically When calling this specific endpoint, we want to retrieve a UUID from the incoming request and check if it is still valid in the database before calling other lambdas to do other logic. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Lambda Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html): it fits exactly your use case.

Comment: Is it possible to add a Lambda Authorizer for only one route in the API Gateway ?
I read the documentation but I can't find this piece of information.

Comment: Yeah, sure, in API Gateway you configure authorization at method level, so i.e. you can add a Lambda Authorizer exclusively only on POST /api/test.